# ReactJS Formik hidden field sending null value to server

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new to React i am using FormIK which is posting Form data fine unless i add a hidden field into it.

```
<Field type="hidden" className="form-control" name="hiddenField" />
```

When i post form it sends the Null value of hidden field
Also i have provided initial values to Formik

```
<Formik initialValues={{
first_name:'',last_name:'',username:'',email:'',password:'',
password_confirmation:'',distributor:'',phone_number:'',address:'',country:'',
state:'',city:'',zip_code:'',hiddenField:''
}} >
```

Is there any thing missing ?

Comment: How do you update your `hiddenField`, the code you post shown that `hiddenField` has initial value as empty. Do you use `setFieldValue` to update it somewhere ?

Comment: I managed it  by `setFieldValue` in the Form field callback function.

Comment: @ThaiDuongTran Please review the answer if that worked for you next time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how i managed the hidden field value in Formik

Passed the `setFieldValue` as argument before the  tage

```
{({ values, errors, touched, handleSubmit, setFieldValue , isSubmitting }) => (
<Form>
<div className="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="hidden" value="testing" name="hiddenField" />
```

Then I managed to changed it onClick method (can be used as required)

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" 
onClick={() => {setFieldValue("hiddenField", "yourValueHere OR dynamicVariable"); }} 
disabled={isSubmitting}>Register</button>
```

Answer (score 19):

I just used ran into this issue as well. My work around was to just add an initial value, and not even use a hidden field. The result was, in `onSubmit()`, the `values` object contained my hidden field key with the `initialValues` value.

I'd like to know if anyone knows of the correct way to go about this? My way seems a bit hacky?

Comment: Your way is perfectly fine. I would actually mark your answer as correct one.

Comment: I would add the supplement that if you are using a yup `validationSchema` you need to add the field to the schema too.